# Add custom class to link outputted by views

Tags: views, navigation

I'm using views to output a link. The user gets two fields in which to add the href and the text on the link. I wan't them to be able to put a class on the link as well. How can I do this?

In views I have set a fixed class to all those links, but I wan't to be able to add another class if I wan't to, from the backend.

Comment: you want to add class to anchor tag `<a>` ?

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do.

Comment: Are you only asking how to add the class to the Views output, or do you also want help adding the form element and storing the data for the classname?

Comment: Both. I'm not sure I understand, but I wan't a form element in the backend where the user can put some text that will become the class of the link.

Comment: OK. And currently you have a [link field](http://drupal.org/project/link) attached to an entity, and that's what the user edits, yeah? (Also, are you using Views to display a list of links attached to different entities, or are you using it as a convenient way to display the link attached to just one entity?)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this on the server side with a Views field `tpl.php` file, or on the client side with jQuery.

---

**For the server side method**, go to your `view edit -> Advaced -> Theme:Information -> chose your field` you need to create a one template file (in your theme/templates folder):

For example: if your field name is title you will see something similar to this:

```
Field Content: Title (ID: title): - click on it and cope the code

views-view-field--YOURVIEWNAME--page--title.tpl.php -paste it here
```

Now you have 3 variables to play with

```
 * - $field: The field handler object that can process the input
 * - $row: The raw SQL result that can be used
 * - $output: The processed output that will normally be used.
```

Easy way - do it with `str_replace` function :D

```
<?php $output = str_replace('<a', '<a class="someclass"', $output); ?>
<?php  print $output; ?>
```

Also you can play around with`($row)` and create your own output. To easy development install [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module so you can `dpm($row)` and see what it contains. or you can `print_r($row)`. have fun <3

---

**Fastest way to do this with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)** you can simple add class to your `fields` `anchor` tag.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.your-views-class-name .your-view-field a').addClass('someclass');
}
```

open firebug(int firefox) and find your view class name and field class name which contains `anchor tag` and add class to it. You can do this in YOURTHEME - scripts.js or any other js file you want.

Comment: Yeah I know I can do it with jQuery. It's just that if feels wrong doing it that way. I don't mind it for small fixes, but to use jQuery to add classes for lot's of content just feels wrong.

Comment: yea, i can agree with you, probabaly you will need to create `template` for that field and manage classes there, need some research about this

Comment: Yeah I heard you can create templates for views. But I don't understand how that will give me a backend field to input the class name. However, I'm new to Drupal and views in particular so I have no clue really.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: I'm trying to implement this solution. Is it necessary to implement the jquery and template file or is only creating the template file enough? I'm asking this as I did the template file but not getting the good result...

Comment: Note that [the .tpl.php file is by default ignored if you rewrite this field into another field using replacement patterns](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198923/views-is-ignoring-my-field-tpl-php-file-when-the-field-is-used-as-a-replacement). p.s. I've editted this answer so that it's clearer that there are two approaches, and to put the good practice approach first.