# Views is ignoring my field .tpl.php file when the field is used as a replacement pattern in a rewritten field

Tags: 7, views, entities

I've been trying to [modify a multiple-values field in a view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198894/how-to-add-a-class-to-the-a-link-elements-within-a-multiple-values-field-in-a). I thought I'd found the answer, [creating a custom `.tpl.php`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/61178/2646) file using the naming structures detailed in Views UI's "Theme information" popup.

However, it seems that these `tpl.php` files are only respected when the field is output immediately, and not when it's set to be excluded from the display and then rewritten into another field using a replacement pattern. Views is seeing the file, and uses it if I don't have "exclude" ticked, but if I use a re-write pattern for the field, Views completely ignores the `tpl.php` file.

This happens regardless of whether "Use field template" is ticked for this field in Views UI's field Style Settings.

I almost always aggregate my fields like this to control the HTML output. How can I make Views respect my `tpl.php` file when re-writing the field content into another field?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the other method? Using template.php. I don't have time to test this, so consider this as a *possible* answer.

Add the following code to the bottom of your **template.php** file (located in `/sites/all/themes/yourtheme/` folder)

```
function themename_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){

      if ($vars['view']->name == "view_name" && $vars['view']->current_display == "block_1"){
        $vars['fields']['field_name']->content = 'hello world';
      }
    }
```

- replace **themename** with your theme name
- replace **view_name** with your view name
- replace **block_1** with your [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg)
- replace **field_name** with your field name